# LINQ : Group by Multiple Columns with Maximum for one column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have query below in SQL. Tried using different options in linq to get the exact         matching result from SQL to my Center code, here is my code using linq.

But could not get it.

SQL query is (which gives correct result)

```
Select prdCode, Max(prdID) from products 
    GROUP BY prdCode
    order by prdCode
```

Tried below in linq

```
from prd in Entities.Products
    where prd.prdEnabled == true
    group prd by new { prd.prdCode, prd.prdID } into gcs 
    select new { prdID = gcs.Key.prdID, prdCode = gcs.Key.prdCode }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that code snippet supposed to be an attempt at converting the SQL into Linq? If so, why does the LINQ query filter the products by their `prdEnabled` property, and the SQL doesnt? They dont seem to be equivalent at all

Comment: Please edit the question title, the answer you accepted and the question title are not relevant. The answer doesn't group multiple columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from prd in Entities.Products
where prd.prdEnabled == true
group prd by prd.prdCode into gcs 
orderby gcs.Key
select new { prdCode = gcs.Key, prdID= gcs.Max(g => g.prdID) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should match your SQL query

```
Entities.Producs.Where(prod=> prod.prdEnabled)
                .GroupBy(prod => prod.prdCode)
                .Select(group => new{ prdCode = group.Key, prdID = group.Max(prod => prod.prdID) } )
                .OrderBy(x => x.prdCode);
```

1. Filter the products by their `prdEnabled` property
2. Group the products by their code
3. For each group, select the code and the maximum id
4. Sort by code